# How to get a default value from a stored procedure, given a wrong parameter ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin
    select count(t.TBarcode) as barcodeCount, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t
    where TBarcode=@carid

    group by t.paid,t.status,t.DelDate

    declare @transid integer=null;
   select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1
end
end
```

If I pass `carid` a wrong number, an empty table is returned; but I'd like it to instead get `T.Barcode` count as 0.

How can I do that?

Comment: I spent time correcting, and improving your question; why did you undo the edit?

Comment: You keep breaking your post... do you need some help?

Comment: yes sir,,,still am not able to find out the answer

Comment: If T.Barcode returns 0, which will result in t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate columns?

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove filter in from where condition then .

Try following store procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation111]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin
select count(case when t.TBarcode is null or t.TBarcode!=@carid then 0 else 1 end) as cnt,  t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
from Transaction_tbl t
group by t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate;

declare @transid integer=null;

select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1
end
end
```

Comment: i executed this stord procedure,,,but am getting wrong answer,,if i pass wrong carid or correcet carid getting wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to try this.

```
    alter procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
    @carid nvarchar(100)=null,
@countTbar int 
    as
    begin
        select @countTbar=  select count(t.TBarcode) as barcodeCount
        from Transaction_tbl t
        where TBarcode=@carid  group by t.paid,t.status,t.DelDate
 if(@countTbar is null)
    begin
    return 0
    end

        select count(t.TBarcode) as barcodeCount, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
        from Transaction_tbl t
        where TBarcode=@carid

        group by t.paid,t.status,t.DelDate

        declare @transid integer=null;
       select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
    if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
    begin
    return 1
    end
    end
```

Comment: @user2535939  i dont think your stored procedure return table. what exactly you want to return?

Comment: if i given @carid is wrong number,,i want get T.Tbarcode count is 0,,Thats all,,,

Comment: @user2535939 i forgo to put comma try once i will update again

Comment: dear sir,,,I try to put comma that time it self,,,,then also showing same error